# Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code in Holistically-Nested Edge Detection (HED)

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, edge-detection

I am currently working on an image processing project and have encountered an issue with the apply_hed function. The function aims to perform HED (Holistically-Nested Edge Detection) on an input image using OpenCV's dnn module. However, I am encountering an unknown C++ exception during the execution of the net.forward() method.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
# Net is loaded with the pretrained model and weights
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('deploy.prototxt', 'hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel')

def apply_hed(image):
    # Get the width and height
    height, width = image.shape[:2]

    # Perform HED on the resized image
    net.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=1.0, size=(width, height),
                                      mean=(tuple(np.average(image, axis=(0, 1)))), swapRB=False, crop=False))
    hed_output = net.forward()  # <-- Exception occurs here
    hed_output = hed_output[0, 0, :, :]
    hed = (255 * hed_output).astype("uint8")
    
    return hed
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
----> 8 hed_output = net.forward()

error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

I am using a pretrained HED model from the following sources:

[deploy.prototxt](https://github.com/s9xie/hed/blob/master/examples/hed/deploy.prototxt)
[hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel](https://vcl.ucsd.edu/hed/hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel)

Interestingly, the code runs without issues if the input image dimensions are below 3000 pixels in height and width. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**What I tried:**

I tried using different versions of OpenCV within a virtual environment to explore potential version-specific compatibility issues. I tested multiple versions to see if the exception persisted or if there were any improvements. Unfortunately, the issue remained unresolved across different OpenCV versions.

**Expectation:**

I expected the `net.forward()` method to successfully compute the HED output for the given image, and subsequently, the function would return the edge-detected result (`hed`). The goal was to integrate HED into my image processing pipeline.

**Actual Result:**

Unfortunately, during the execution of `net.forward()`, an unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code occurred. The error message provided little information about the specific nature of the exception, making it challenging to identify the root cause of the issue. Notably, **I observed that the code runs without issues if the input image dimensions are below 3000 pixels in height and width.** This led me to suspect that the exception might be related to the image size.